# What is the life expectancy of Tarebia granifera?

Tags: aquarium, snails

A few days ago I found a few snails in my aquarium. As it looks like it seems they are of the [Tarebia granifera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarebia_granifera) species.

When I looked them up I found quite a few things about them BUT one thing I didn't find anything about is their maximum life span.

Thus how old can they become?

Comment: my (unsourced) guess is between 6 months to 2 years, if we compare to similar snails.. The wikipedia page also tells 3 to 12 months for "maturation" of new snails. These will reproduce a lot so I wouldn't worry about lifespan... I can tell you they will live longer in cold water, faster in warmer water. Depends also what they eat and how much. By the way did you double-check that they're no Malaysian Trumpet Snails ?

Comment: I'Ve got no clue how to differentate those? (they have spiral like housings and its about 3,5cm long from almost point size to that it took about a month I would say)

Comment: how are the colors? malaysian sometimes have white tips. A good picture could help to identify. MTS are very very common in aquaria

Comment: @Manuki  https://imgur.com/ywwTNWc  that is the best pic I got (from the descriptions on wikipedia I thought its a tarebia granifera)

Comment: it does look a lot like MTS.. and a lot like Tarebia also.. I think MTS is more long and Tarebia more round-ish from google images.. maybe to search how to differentiate these two. I know MTS like to burrow under sand. Do get a pic of the body if possible, even tho the bodies are similar too

Comment: @Manuki It is never high enough above the stones that the body can be seen onnly the house. Still though it doesnt look like it tries to burrow itself under the stones most of the time (only once it looked like it so far)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be looking at both, the Malaysian Trumpet Snail as well as the Tarebia Granifera.

## Tarebia Granifera

According to this shop selling them (I am not affiliated to that shop in any way), the life expectancy is about **3 years**: [Link](https://www.garnelen-guemmer.de/genoppte-turmdeckelschnecke-mieniplotia-scabra) (German website)

> Alterserwartung: ca. 3 Jahre

This other German website on pets claims a life expectancy of max **3 years**: [Link](http://www.grumpi.de/haustiere/aquaristik/arten/schnecken/turmdeckelschnecke)

> Lebenserwartung: bis 3 Jahre

According to these research notes, the life expectancy is **more than 1 year**: [Link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1003.5479&rep=rep1&type=pdf) [Alternative link](https://watermark.silverchair.com/680399.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAqgwggKkBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggKVMIICkQIBADCCAooGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMdOniWthhgrjTkeR3AgEQgIICW48nmVYZPVWss44fq4u7Bgdh0VkVJ2TWXtuSzOzV1-e3fPuNcDLykowNGhr9Zh1DRms0ZAzUyzRNH-76etmi6WMXPxWJB3BTWw4Q-9dEwdI9pXEnAyrMhpsPTLeurVI1yBgALMLUbrEjonyTRNXlrDORrNb8C1SHCr1KjP0rbI_ikj1JqP0PIqD1fSAkwy0Iiwk2Z0rL1py5NRnFRHcbmnKXNcw4tnBI14GpEU7JUrL8BhfozfjFRq0V4CnI1B3MzSBzD1lLEvgBvXv1iEk7pVi-4do0YhfOHa4LCbm077FLmFqLl39HoVLvJ1tSJWZmKtrpqn1nSkSVlowhNesgPiVoOr0P0r5lDPjD58-rQ12bwRXFYPfR42GrVbrjZ9IdQptGJaIujT8ltZKm0V5SupW3MWvWG-a0004cLieeGy7agl7nZ4hf1a2mI0alycW0DRf0M1h1jE4Ij9ClbQU_YlboO-_Pk2QAH9zH5l7nuwshN__odNSLek4pZIZCejaTmFTwSasqsRjA-UmKdyGYVLNmlTGShTy9p0IRKFyEw0zmQqXftWhj4GBrf7aK3DLYaMFogh_IPp-dLNsVk5isWMQk3SWzP4S6aVcXahXh8IU3ydl7qQCIQ6CzLsKikIyQMqUrC4Nk1Pngtb9aHcODLlD-VIG-kVJDpVX_Krg0qytFmIvQ7Ks9xGB3y6cIFmPybhGNb4EErg2lUmeUqvZ5VbqffJJ9EvrVX_lyenrbyTVBxpQUHWlBy_x1b9fjqIUR5keCF7PRVZIEEs1nYSvfcLgaXjrRR5TBe7FYrQ)

> In terms of its bionomics, studies in Cuba9–13
> showed it to be a relatively long-lived species with an expected
> life-span of more than a year.

Then, on this German kind-of-forum website a user named "Fynn Günther" claims a life expectancy of **2 to 5 years** for the whole family of Thiaridae, without specifying the exact species. Also this claim is unsourced.

> Turmdeckelschnecken kann man im Aquarium halten. Sie benötigen, um sich gut fortbewegen zu können, feinen Sand oder Kies als Untergrund. Die optimale Wassertemperatur liegt bei 22-28 Grad Celsius und das Wasser sollte klar und sauber sein. Außerdem bevorzugt die Turmdeckelschnecke als Lebensraum Wurzeln und Blätter und ernährt sich von verrottendem Pflanzenmaterial. **Die Lebenserwartung liebt bei 2-5 Jahren.** (emphasis mine)

## Malaysian Trumpet Snail

According to this page, the life expectancy of this species is **about a year**: [Link](https://www.aquariumcarebasics.com/freshwater-snails/malaysian-trumpet-snails)

> Usually, Malaysian trumpet Snails live about a year, though sometimes some snails can live a little longer.

**The Aquarium Guide** approves: [Link](https://www.theaquariumguide.com/articles/malaysian-trumpet-snails#The_lifespan_of_Malaysian_Trumpet_Snails)

> In general, Malaysian Trumpet Snails live about one year.

## Conclusion

I'd expect them to live for **1 to 3 years**. Considering that they can give birth to a baby snail every 12 hours